# No module named 'quantlib'

Tags: python, anaconda, quantlib

I [installed quantlib](https://anaconda.org/tonyroberts/quantlib) via `conda install -c tonyroberts quantlib`, and i also have this in anaconda's installed libs:
[image]

but i have an error

```
import quantlib as ql
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quantlib'

Comment: Are you sure you're executing the program using the correct Python installation? Also, have you seen the [official Quantlib installation instructions](https://www.quantlib.org/install.shtml) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import it as:

```
import QuantLib as ql
```